# Yii2 pjax don't update div in container

Tags: javascript, yii2, pjax

I have code like this in my view:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id'=>'client-info']);?>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8" id="some-div">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-8" id="other-div">

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I am updating container via js like this

```
 $.pjax.reload({container:'#client-info',timeout:false});
```

Can I prevent #some-div from updating? 
I need pjax to update all except one #some-div. I cannot change pjax begin and end position because then I will have to change page layout fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple pjax sections.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id'=>'some-id-one']);?>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
        <div class="col-8" id="some-div">

        </div>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id'=>'some-id-two']);?>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-8" id="other-div">

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And then you need to reload both containers.

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#some-id-one',timeout:false});
$.pjax.reload({container:'#some-id-two',timeout:false});
```

Probably you can have better solution by modifying pjax.